# Conditionally set style if sibling element exists in PURE CSS

Tags: html, css

I have the following structure, where second element may or may not appear.

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="firstElement"></div>
    <div class="secondElement"></div>
</div>
```

I want to conditionally set styles on `.firstElement` ONLY if `.secondElement` exists.

Is there a way to do this with PURE CSS? With either sibling selectors/ parent selectors?

Thanks!

Comment: that's what I thought but wasn't sure with all the CSS selectors

Answer (score 20):

In general, no. CSS reads forwards/down the DOM - it won't read backwards/up. But with this markup, you could use `:not(:last-child)`

```css
.firstElement:not(:last-child) {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="firstElement">target this</div>
    <div class="secondElement"></div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="firstElement">not this</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I like it. A good creative solution.